# Vim - insert a column of text/insert repeated characters to multiple rows

Tags: vim

I have  a dataset like by inserting a new column of data between 1st column

```
     M1    M2   M3   M4
G1    1     2    3    4
G2    4     3    2    1
...
G120  1     3    4    2
```

I would like to modify dataset with another column of data in vim to

```
     M1    M2   M3   M4
G1    1     1    2    3    4
G2    1     4    3    2    1
...
G120  1     1    3    4    2
```

Comment: I cannot understand the requirement. use the code block to format your input/output examples.

Comment: I need to inset a one column of same character (say 1) in all rows before 2nd column (i.e. before the column name M1).

Answer (score 2):

i assume you use \t to align your text. then regex can be used

```
:%s/^\(G\d\+\)/\1\t1/
```

Comment: Can this be made to work for any other space-character? You could define the spaces as `\2` and insert this instead of the tab.

Comment: @SimonG sure. but it's hard to predict the alignment after 1 in M1. the other way is to change all alignment space into \t.

Answer (score 2):

Vim's blockwise visual mode, `ctrl-v`, is probably the best way to do this.

In particular, you should use "Visual-block Insert" (vim help: `:help v_b_I`)

With your example, with the cursor at `|1|` in normal mode:

```
     M1    M2   M3   M4
G1   |1|    2    3    4
G2    4     3    2    1
...
G120  1     3    4    2
```

Do the following:

- `ctrl-v` - start visual blockwise selection
- `3j` - extend selection 3 lines down (can substitute any other movement command here)
- `I` - begin block insert mode
- `1<space><space><space><space><space>` - the text you want inserted every line
- `Esc` or `ctrl-[` (its synonym) - complete the visual-block insert

Visual block insert can also be used to indent/unindent multiple lines, append text to every line (even if they don't end on the same column), etc, etc.